# How we can open /dev/video0 or any v4l2 node with ffmpeg for capture raw frames and encode it in jpeg format?

Tags: c, linux, video, ffmpeg, v4l2

I am new in video domain . I am working now on ffmpeg , I use ffmpeg command line but there is very big issue and challenge for use ffmpeg in my own c code .So I read some tutorials like dranger.com etc . But I am not able to capture v4l2 or my laptop /dev/video0 node . I want capture raw video stream and overlay it with some text and then compress it in jpeg format . I have a little idea and that is in following code that code is working for ant .mp4 format or encoded file but not work on /dev/video0 node format . so please any one help me . Thanks in advance !!

please see following code snapshot that is a tutorial1.c from dranger.com :

```
#include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>
#include <libavformat/avformat.h>
#include <libswscale/swscale.h>

#include <stdio.h>

void SaveFrame(AVFrame *pFrame, int width, int height, int iFrame) {
  FILE *pFile;
  char szFilename[32];
  int  y;

  // Open file
  sprintf(szFilename, "frame%d.ppm", iFrame);
  pFile=fopen(szFilename, "wb");
  if(pFile==NULL)
    return;

  // Write header
  fprintf(pFile, "P6\n%d %d\n255\n", width, height);

  // Write pixel data
  for(y=0; y<height; y++)
    fwrite(pFrame->data[0]+y*pFrame->linesize[0], 1, width*3, pFile);

  // Close file
  fclose(pFile);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  AVFormatContext *pFormatCtx = NULL;
  int             i, videoStream;
  AVCodecContext  *pCodecCtx = NULL;
  AVCodec         *pCodec = NULL;
  AVFrame         *pFrame = NULL; 
  AVFrame         *pFrameRGB = NULL;
  AVPacket        packet;
  int             frameFinished;
  int             numBytes;
  uint8_t         *buffer = NULL;

  AVDictionary    *optionsDict = NULL;
  struct SwsContext      *sws_ctx = NULL;

  if(argc < 2) {
    printf("Please provide a movie file\n");
    return -1;
  }
  // Register all formats and codecs
  av_register_all();

  // Open video file
  if(avformat_open_input(&pFormatCtx, argv[1], NULL, NULL)!=0)
    return -1; // Couldn't open file

  // Retrieve stream information
  if(avformat_find_stream_info(pFormatCtx, NULL)<0)
    return -1; // Couldn't find stream information

  // Dump information about file onto standard error
  av_dump_format(pFormatCtx, 0, argv[1], 0);

  // Find the first video stream
  videoStream=-1;
  for(i=0; i<pFormatCtx->nb_streams; i++)
    if(pFormatCtx->streams[i]->codec->codec_type==AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO) {
      videoStream=i;
      break;
    }
  if(videoStream==-1)
    return -1; // Didn't find a video stream

  // Get a pointer to the codec context for the video stream
  pCodecCtx=pFormatCtx->streams[videoStream]->codec;

  // Find the decoder for the video stream
  pCodec=avcodec_find_decoder(pCodecCtx->codec_id);
  if(pCodec==NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Unsupported codec!\n");
    return -1; // Codec not found
  }
  // Open codec
  if(avcodec_open2(pCodecCtx, pCodec, &optionsDict)<0)
    return -1; // Could not open codec

  // Allocate video frame
  pFrame=av_frame_alloc();

  // Allocate an AVFrame structure
  pFrameRGB=av_frame_alloc();
  if(pFrameRGB==NULL)
    return -1;

  // Determine required buffer size and allocate buffer
  numBytes=avpicture_get_size(AV_PIX_FMT_RGB24, pCodecCtx->width,
                  pCodecCtx->height);
  buffer=(uint8_t *)av_malloc(numBytes*sizeof(uint8_t));

  sws_ctx =
    sws_getContext
    (
        pCodecCtx->width,
        pCodecCtx->height,
        pCodecCtx->pix_fmt,
        pCodecCtx->width,
        pCodecCtx->height,
        AV_PIX_FMT_RGB24,
        SWS_BILINEAR,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        NULL
    );

  // Assign appropriate parts of buffer to image planes in pFrameRGB
  // Note that pFrameRGB is an AVFrame, but AVFrame is a superset
  // of AVPicture
  avpicture_fill((AVPicture *)pFrameRGB, buffer, AV_PIX_FMT_RGB24,
         pCodecCtx->width, pCodecCtx->height);

  // Read frames and save first five frames to disk
  i=0;
  while(av_read_frame(pFormatCtx, &packet)>=0) {
    // Is this a packet from the video stream?
    if(packet.stream_index==videoStream) {
      // Decode video frame
      avcodec_decode_video2(pCodecCtx, pFrame, &frameFinished, 
               &packet);

      // Did we get a video frame?
      if(frameFinished) {
    // Convert the image from its native format to RGB
        sws_scale
        (
            sws_ctx,
            (uint8_t const * const *)pFrame->data,
            pFrame->linesize,
            0,
            pCodecCtx->height,
            pFrameRGB->data,
            pFrameRGB->linesize
        );

    // Save the frame to disk
    if(++i<=5)
      SaveFrame(pFrameRGB, pCodecCtx->width, pCodecCtx->height, 
            i);
      }
    }

    // Free the packet that was allocated by av_read_frame
    av_free_packet(&packet);
  }

  // Free the RGB image
  av_free(buffer);
  av_free(pFrameRGB);

  // Free the YUV frame
  av_free(pFrame);

  // Close the codec
  avcodec_close(pCodecCtx);

  // Close the video file
  avformat_close_input(&pFormatCtx);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi... !! Please there have any one which can help , I searching about that and then I find v4l2 lib api and I alos use it now my /dev/video0 is opened using v4l2 open routine but I am not able to get frame from then :( please any one help .